# Ag-grid: How to get count of search result data after api.setQuickFilter on master and details table

Tags: ag-grid, master-detail, ag-grid-react

How we can apply [setQuickFilter](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-quick/#setting-the-quick-filter) on [Detail Grids](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/master-detail-grids/#detail-grid-definition). to find data left after the filter.

Tried to use `api.setQuickFilter(document.getElementById('filter-text-box').value)` where api is GridApi of master table.
it's just doing search in master table and but not in Detail Grids.
so we tried below

```
// first on details  
api.forEachDetailGridInfo((detailGridInfo)
{
  detailGridInfo.api.setQuickFilter(document.getElementById('filter-text-box').value);
});
// then on master 
api.setQuickFilter(document.getElementById('filter-text-box').value)
```

But its removing the all details table if nothing matches on details table then not able to search on mater table.

- Able to search both detail data and master data for a string.
- Get the count of filter result after filter.

Comment: [forEachNodeAfterFilter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-rowNodes-forEachNodeAfterFilter)  and [forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-rowNodes-forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort) are two such functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it will help someone who is looking for such case.

```
// assuming where api=gridApi;

let rowMasterData = [];
let rowDetailsData = [];
    
// first on details  
api.forEachDetailGridInfo((detailGridInfo)
{
  detailGridInfo?.api?.setQuickFilter(document.getElementById('filter-text-box').value);
 detailGridInfo?.api?.forEachNodeAfterFilter(node => {
      rowDetailsData?.push(node.data);
    });
});
// then on master 
api?.setQuickFilter(document.getElementById('filter-text-box').value)
api?.forEachNodeAfterFilter(node => {
      rowMasterData?.push(node.data);
    });
const totalCount = rowMasterData?.length + rowDetailsData?.length;
```